# Asking whether help is in need

Tags: grammar, difference

Are all these sentences valid and common? Especially in a shop or in work areas? In factories?

1. How can I help you?
2. What can I help you with?
3. Is there anything I can help you with?
4. Are you needing any help?
5. Something I can help you with?

Comment: Ace Hardware wants you! They especially like #5.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I rolf-ed here. lol. @@SovereignSun, there are so many ways to   ask if you can help or want to help someone. This topic/query is quite broad and might be considered off-topic (proofreading). Considering this, is there anything else we can help you with?

Comment: @shin Of these five which are common?

Answer (score 1):

Are you needing any help? -- This is awkward and not said. Better would be: 'do you need any help?' or 'Are you in need of assistance?'

Something I can help you with? -- Better would be: 'Is there something I can help you with?'

Answer (score 0):

Sentences 1-4 are correct. However, in the context that you described, sentences 1-3 are best.

4. "Are you needing any help?" is fine grammatically, but does not sound natural.
5. "Something I can help you with?" is grammatically incorrect, however, it is commonly used in spoken English. To a native ear it will sound pleasant but technically is bad grammar.